# Dialogflow slot validation from database

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to validate my slot from database.

I train bot to identify entity `name` and return as parameter `personName`

User phrase - tell me details of Mr.Jhon

In above phrase "Jhon" will be identified as personName, now this parameter is passed to webhook for validition from database.

If database have more than one entries for name "jhon"

Response will be - I found follow persons with name jhon -

1. jhon abc
2. jhon xyz

Kindly tell whose details you want?

Now here, when I entered anyone option form given set of entries,
Bot response is  - Sorry, I missed that

conversation is as follows -

> user - I want details of Mr.Jhon
>
> Bot - I found various person with name Jhon - 
>          1. Jhon abc
>          2. Jhon xyz
>          3. wxz Jhon
>
> whose details you want?
>   user - Jhon abc
>
> bot  -  sorry, I missed that

I use flask (python) for webhook development

Comment: It looks to me that the DialogFlow is not trained to understand the second question, maybe it only understands something similar to question 1?

Another option is that the OutputContext Lifespan (set in DialogFlow) is 1, so it is no longer available after the first answer

Comment: here, 1. Jhon abc 2. Jhon xyz 3. wxz Jhon are send by fulfillment using webhook. main issue is during 1st question I am just giving 1st name to which agent replies me with all matching names in database so second time when I select one name form given option it is not matching to any intent but previously when I train respective intent with single name it was working properly, now I have to use same entity in some other intent that why removed single name training phrase.

Comment: Can you update your question to show screen shots of the Intents you have setup? The "sorry, I missed that" suggests that it is being caught by the Fallback Intent, so we would need to see the Intents you have to understand why they aren't matching.

Comment: I would rather suggest using a list, and when a user makes a selection out of the list of names, you can easily get the option selected. This is helpful when a bot is not trained for the dynamic options